# Travis CI seems to be reading from the wrong stdlib

Tags: c++, clang, c++14, travis-ci

I'm just getting started with using travis-CI, so I apologize if this is a silly or obvious question.

Following the instructions [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/cpp/#Clang):

I wrote the following travis.yml

```
language: cpp

dist: trusty

matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      compiler: gcc
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - g++-7
      env:
        - MATRIX_EVAL="CC=gcc-7 && CXX=g++-7"
    - os: linux
      compiler: clang
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - llvm-toolchain-trusty-5.0
          packages:
            - clang-5.0
      env:
        - MATRIX_EVAL="CC=clang-5.0 && CXX=clang++-5.0"

before_install:
    - eval "${MATRIX_EVAL}"

script:
    - mkdir build
    - cd build
    - cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON ..
    - cmake --build .
    - ctest
```

Which causes the following error in the clang build:

> /home/travis/build/path_to_project/./include/abulafia/support/type_traits.h:20:12:
> error: no member named 'decay_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean
> 'decay'?
>
> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/type_traits:1725:11:
> note: 'decay' declared here

When compiling with the following command:

`cd /home/travis/build/path_to_project/build/tests/char_set && /usr/bin/clang++-5.0    -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -std=c++17 -I/home/travis/build/path_to_project/./include -I/home/travis/build/path_to_project/googletest/googletest/include    -o CMakeFiles/char_set_tests.dir/test_any.cpp.o -c`

Which tells me it's loading gcc's libraries. Is there something I'm not understanding right here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by installing g++7 alongside clang, to upgrade the standard library. The relevant matrix entry becomes:

```
matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      addons:
        apt:
          sources:
            - llvm-toolchain-trusty-5.0
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - clang-5.0
            - g++-7
      env: MATRIX_EVAL="CC=clang-5.0 && CXX=clang++-5.0"
```

Replacing this into the OP's yaml should do the trick. Note: `compiler: clang` was in excess – its effects get overridden by the `eval "${MATRIX_EVAL}"` trick.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is a well-known issue with the travis-ci build environment. It is compiling and linking against the default ubuntu-trusty `libstdc++`, which is the gcc 4-series stdlib and not even C++11 conforming.

See [an issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6300) I opened a long time ago.

If you need a C++14 `libstdc++` with travis-ci, you should use docker and make a more recent ubuntu image. That's the best workaround AFAIK.

Comment: But my gcc 7 build is working fine in C++17, so there has to be a way of getting the proper lib without making an entire new docker image.

Comment: That's right, you have the gcc 7 compiler, and you are enabling C++17, but it is reading the `libstdc++` headers and so file from the OS, so you are getting a janky C++17/C++03 build. It is doing this because it knows you probably have some external dependencies. Any dependencies that come from apt-get and need `libstdc++`, will need the gcc-4 series `libstdc++`, and you won't be able to link to both versions of `libstdc++` at once. If your project has any dependencies that you satisfy using `apt-get`, your best bet is to use a docker image.

Comment: If you build the entire compiler and standard library from source, in your home directory, you can configure the compiler to use that version of the stdlib and make programs that require that version of the stdlib. But the gcc-5 you get from ppa's in ubuntu trusty won't be like that, because it's not useful to anyone running trusty. They will be set up to use trusty stdlib and make useful programs on trusty. It boils down to, if the trusty version of `libstdc++` isn't acceptable to you then you should use docker.

Comment: I mean, if your dependencies are small enough, you could compile them all yourself, and skip apt-get. It really depends how big your project is. I have done stuff like that in some projects. But it rapidly becomes more maintainable to use docker, that's my 2 cents.